# ckeditor classic has transparent text

Tags: text, ckeditor5

I have these ckeditors on my website that work but when you go to type text it's clear?  Can only be seen if highlighted.  I tried adding style of color black on the textarea but nothing?

I include the cdn:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/37.1.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

then have a textarea

```
<textarea id="answer" name="hello">Hello world</textarea>
```

then the jquery to make it work:

```
                            ClassicEditor
                                .create( document.querySelector( '#question' ) )
                                .then( editor => {
                                        console.log( editor );
                                        question = editor;
                                } )
                                .catch( error => {
                                        console.error( error );
                                } );
```

But I can't see the text.  The weirdest thing is randomly one textarea does have black text and there's nothing different about it than the others??